# How can we call a web service in a different thread in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Can anyone tell me how to implement background execution in iOS .like i have to call a Webservice in background so it doesn't interrpt the main UI.

Comment: Can you please tell how are you calling your web service? Are you using maybe AFNetworking? Some code for example.

Answer (score 0):

use following code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Do background work

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Update UI
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can write a service class with completion block (closure) that call your webservice. And then use GCD dispatch_async to call your service. So that the function call will be run in a background instead of main thread.

And update the UI in the completion block.

For GCD tutorial, you can refer to 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    int result = <some really long calculation that takes seconds to complete>;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateMyUIWithResult:result];
    });    
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for using background thread and main thread.

Hope it helps you.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0),^{

   //do your web service calls to not to disturb main thread.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

       //here you can do what you want with main thread
       //once you got data you can get it on to main thread and execute the operation

   });
  });
```